# ionic 2 Duplicate identifier 'export='

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am facing an error when I am trying to deploy and run an android app.

> ionic run android

Here is the error I am facing. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
[11:47:12]  Error: Error at C:/Users/adirz/myapps/HaverSami/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:409:3
[11:47:12]  Duplicate identifier 'export='.
[11:47:12]  Error at C:/Users/adirz/myapps/HaverSami/node_modules/@types/firebase/index.d.ts:326:2
[11:47:12]  Duplicate identifier 'export='.
[11:47:12]  ngc failed
[11:47:12]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[11:47:12]  Error: Error
```

Comment: add this to your tsconfig.json
`{
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}`

Comment: hey, i already have this in my project.

Comment: remove node_modules and try to do npm install again it might solve the problem then try ionic run android