# Duplicate Identifier 'Map' in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the following error suddenly happens

```
Typescript Error
Duplicate identifier 'Map'.
/node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts
```

Tried this way but it wasnt fixed

[ionic 2 Duplicate identifier 'export='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801980/ionic-2-duplicate-identifier-export)

my tsconfig file looks like below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "types": [
    "jasmine"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  }
}
```

ionic -v 3.2.0

Comment: are you including jasmine in types array because of type declarations?

Answer (score 0):

Check the section on @types, typeRoots and types
in [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) docs.

Because you have included

```
"types": [
  "jasmine"
],
```

Typescript will only pick `jasmine` type declarations. You should add `googlemaps` to the array as well.

```
"types": [
      "jasmine",
      "googlemaps
    ],
```

Or remove the types array from tsconfig.json as typescript is configured to look at @types from node_modules by default.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39827904/4826457) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for the note , i tried both ways but still i have issue

Comment: same error? did you try `"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
]`